# The if expression can be replaced with 'test' (simplifiable-if-expression)

Tags: python, if-statement, pylint

I am trying to figure out how to solve my Pylint issue that I am getting here. I am newer to coding and Python and never really been taught about simplifying if expressions.

I started with this

```py
if variable_name == Labels.INVALID:
    marked_invalid = True
else:
    marked_invalid = False
```

Pylint gave me an error to that saying:

```
The if statement can be replaced with 'var = bool(test)' (simplifiable-if-statement)
```

So I changed that to this:

```py
marked_invalid = True if variable_name == Labels.INVALID else False
```

Now I am getting the above error message of

```
The if expression can be replaced with 'test' (simplifiable-if-expression)
```

I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: `marked_invalid = bool(variable_name == Labels.INVALID)`?

Comment: Does https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/messages/refactor/simplifiable-if-expression.html make sense to tou ?

Answer (score 13):

The expression `variable_name == Labels.INVALID` has a value of either `True` or `False`, and you're testing this value to see if you should assign either `True` or `False` to `marked_invalid`.

What pylint is suggesting is that you assign the value directly, without testing:

```
marked_invalid = variable_name == Labels.INVALID
```

Sometimes I add parenthesis around the expression, to avoid confusing it for a multi-assignment (`a = b = C`). Not necessary, but (arguably) helps readability:

```
marked_invalid = (variable_name == Labels.INVALID)
```

If `variable_name == Labels.INVALID` is true, then marked_invalid will be true; if it's false, then marked_invalid will be false.

The suggestion mentions `bool(` because your conditions don't have to be just `True/False`. For example, `if my_list:` succeeds if the list is non-empty. So it suggests `bool(` to force the value to be `True/False` (a boolean).